# eclipse, new android application project, "next button" is disabled in section that wants the project name

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I want to start programming for android so I downloaded Eclipse and installed ADT Plugin on it and downloaded the Android SDK
Now when I want to create a new android project in "File->New->Android Application Project" it directs me to a page that wants "Application name" & "Project name" etc. so I filled the fields like this:

Application name: Hello

Project name: Hello

Package name: test.example.hello

Minimum required SDK: API8: Android 2.2(Froyo)

Target SDK: API16: Android 4.1(Jelly Bean)

Compile with:

theme: none

But the "Next" button is disabled! in the top of the page it says: " A package name cannot start or end with a dot"
and there is a tiny red thing(cross) near the theme field
so I cannot create a new project
what should I do ?

Comment: I have a screen shot but don't know how to post it here !

Comment: Click on "edit" under your question. Then press Ctrl + G.

Comment: It says that I don't have enough reputation to send a photo!

Comment: Check the answer I've posted.

Comment: @Navid777 which are the option did you get in compile filed ?

Comment: @Navid777 open this http://www.pastie.org/ and past your image there and share that link to me.

Comment: the compile field is empty! and there is no option to choose, so I went to sdk manager & now I'm installing an SDK Platform & waiting to see if this fixes the problem!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that The `SDK Platform` was not installed on my computer, so I opened `Window>Android SDK Manager` and then clicked on `SDK Platform` and then clicked `Install 1 package` and then the problem was solved!

Comment: I just had the same problem. But the problem just appears if you open a workspace in another place as the one you installed the android SDK before. I haven't been occupying on this problem, but maybe you just need to change the directory for the SDK inside the settings. Otherwise you always have to install it again just because of using another place for the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a package name that starts with "com.example". Since your package name is test.example that is not the problem.

As the warning says, see if there are any periods at the start or end of your package.

Check the screenshot. Your window should look exactly like this. And make sure that there are no extra spaces or periods in your package name.

[image]

Comment: the "Compile with" field is empty in my computer! and I cannot choose anything!

Comment: Go to Window -> SDK Manager. Wait for it to load. Make sure you have at least one "SDK Platform" as "Installed"

Comment: i am facing the same problem, and not able to start new project, i checked my sdk manager, i am using adt+eclipse bundle on macbook pro still its asking me to setup sdk path in preferences.

Comment: @Enigma i m sharing you the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.  I went to Help -> "install New Software..." and then I add this URL (make sure it is https.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window>Customize Perspective> Menu Visiblity (there will be NEW option under FILE yu can choose the type of files and projects you want to create right from you FILE>NEW menu.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if Eclipse is still loading the Android tools.

Wait until Eclipse is not busy and try again.
(You can see what Eclipse is doing on the bottom-right of the Eclipse window if using the default layout)

Answer (score 0):

Check in `Window-> Preferences-> General-> Startup and Shutdown` the `Android Development Toolkit` option is deselected, check and restart the eclipse.