# Cannot create Android app in Eclipse. Red x icon by 'Theme'

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I cannot create a new Android project in Eclipse. I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600068/eclipse-new-android-application-project-next-button-is-disabled-in-section-t), and I did already have the SDK platform installed. I have attached a link to the screenshot below, and as you can see, it's saying to enter an application name, but I have clearly already done that.

[image]

Comment: Reinstall Android SDK

Comment: Is there any theme listed in Theme Dropdown ?

Comment: Did you try to select a theme? It seems to me that the message about the name is mistaken (may be a bug in adt) but it clearly prompts you to select a theme...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window->preferences->android and there set the sdk location

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

1. Restart eclipse and switch to a new workspace and try creating a new
   project(that should fix it, as I had fixed my project the same way) if it fails then
2. Reinstall the SDK into different directory

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps found in this other Question solved my problem, [Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6)