# Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Recently I've encountered following error :

[image: screenshot of dialog]

The strangest thing is that I've just updated some package from sdk via working eclipse. There was no information or warning that after this update current adt will crash. I've checked latest updates and can't find new adt even on google's page. Even new adb contain old adt.

From http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html:

> Dependencies: Android SDK Platform-tools revision 18 or later. If you
>   are developing in Eclipse with ADT, note that this version of SDK
>   Tools is designed for use with ADT 22.6.1 and later. If you haven't
>   already, update your ADT Plugin to 22.6.1.

The only solution is to download new standalone eclipse and external plugin for it?
Does the android studio face the same problems?

Environment: linux x64.

Comment: Did you try updating from within Eclipse? Help->Check for Updates

Comment: Yes I did, with no effect. Suppose there was something broken with updates cause I've added some additional values there.

Comment: This walks through this same issue: http://blog.matthewurch.ca/?p=43

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Today me and one of my friends faced the same problem, so I have tried many things like **restarting eclipse**, **checking updates**, etc. but none was working for me.

Then I found a solution from [Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and it's working as a charm for me and also for my friend.

**Follow the steps here:**

- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, in the top-right corner.
- In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
  Name and the following URL for the Location:

  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Click OK.

If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to
  Developer Tools and click Next.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded.
  Click Next. Read and accept the license agreements, then click
  Finish.
- If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or
  validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
- When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: For anybody skim-reading this, it's worth pointing out the bit about trying "http" if "https" doesn't work.  Actually, it was the other way round for me (https worked; http didn't).  But if one protocol doesn't work, try the other.

Comment: Must be Google tightening down security?

Answer (score 14):

I reported [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325) yesterday. Solution is to use *Help -> Install new software* option with **httpS://** protocol (**s** is important). No special downloads or re-installations is needed, just choose the right update site.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the default update site in Android ADT is

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

but this site don't update correctly

And the solution is add a new Install site with protocol https

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click in Help->Install New Software->Add

And use this site to update ADT

Issue : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem, here I have covered steps, surely it will help you.

### Please follow these steps:

1. Help | Install new software
2. Select the ADT update site (there are two, one with http:// and one with https:// If one doesn't work, try the other.
3. Select the developer tools section and press next.
4. You should see a dialog that says "this software is already installed, an update will be performed instead". Clicking ok will lead to 22.6.1 being installed.

## Update 27/03/2014

[They released 22.6.2 and fixed this issue so update your ADT to new version.](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes)

You can see this thread : [Cannot update from ADT 22.3.0. to 22.6.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325)

Comment: That isn't a fix for the issue - #2 still necessary.

Comment: See Google Team has fixed it in new ADT. See here http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Window->Android SDK Manager** and check tha what version you have.
In my case it shows I already have toolkit **22.6.1** installed **but still get the error**. Whether you already have it or not, you can do the following to fix.

- Go to **Help->Install New Software**... In the dialog shown below, click on 'Add' button on the top right side.
- Paste **"https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"** in Location. You can name it anything.
- Click Ok and follow the dialog by clicking Next.
- If prompted with a message sasying you already have it, just agree so that it gets updated (or installed if it wasn't there).

This should resolve the issue.
source : [http://codewriterstips.blogspot.nl](http://codewriterstips.blogspot.nl/2014/03/android-sdk-requires-android-developer.html)

if your android sdk is to old . you must download new android sdk in developer.android.com and , copy past some nececary folder on it .