# Receiving error even after updating ADT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently, I have updated my ADT to 22.6.1 but still whenever I start eclipse following error message comes.
[image]

URL:https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  is already added in Help-> Install New Software 
[image]

Edit:
When I click on What is already installed? ADT version 22.3.0
[image]
Please help me out.

Comment: This post may be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit/22513735#22513735

Comment: @joao2fast4u Thanks for your answer but I have already followed that steps.

Comment: If you click "What is already installed", what does it show for Android DDMS etc? If it shows 22.3, then you should select all on that original screen and proceed

Comment: @nickT In ADT Installation Details I can see two ADT folders one with version 22.3 and other one with 22.6

Comment: I see now, this must be some new way of packaging. I have always got the new API, SDK tools, then added the matching plugin later. That screen tells you you have the plugin but are missing the 'ADT package' which is an unknown concept to me, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated my ADT to 22.6.1 but still whenever I start eclipse following error message comes

I believe this is a symptom of two version of the Android SDKs. One is being used by you from the command line, and the second is being maintained by Eclipse.

To ensure Eclipse uses the version of Android SDK (and NDK) you are maintaining, you need to set both `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`.

For example:

```
$ ls /opt/
android-ndk-r9c  android-sdk  android-studio  eclipse  intel
```

In the example above, I have installed the SDK and NDK in `/opt`. So I set it in `.bashrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
...

# Android goodness
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9c
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk

# Java goodness
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools
```

If you don't set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`, then you need to use Eclipse preferences to set it.

For completeness, the Android folks are the ones who state to use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`. That's because the various tools in the SDK and NDK use the environmental variables. See [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ).

Finally, all this assumes you are using the latest Eclipse plugin. But I've never had problems with the plugins (only with SDK and NDK paths), so I don't believe its your problem. And I could not duplicate it with Kepler on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html and download it to the folder/directory where you have earlier installed the android package [ensure to close eclipse during this time]
2. Do NOT unpack / unzip it but follow these steps: start the eclipse, select Help > Install New Software.
   Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
   Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.0.zip file and click OK.
4. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
5. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
6. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next and follow the guidelines like accepting the license agreements then Finish.
7. Ignore the security warning and click OK. And the When the installation completes, restart the Eclipse.

That should resolve the problem for you. Try to restart your system if required and start the Eclipse again. I've followed the same steps and it worked for me...