# Android DDMS is already installed so an update will be performed instead

Tags: android, plugins, adt

I had the same problem many people had in updating the ADT plugin. So I used this procedure described here:

[Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6/22575048#22575048)

So, I checked Developer Tools and hit the next button. And it says

'Your original request has been modified.
"Android DDMS" so an update will be performed instead.'

But it doesn't do an update, nor does it give me any way to do one.

(Tried to post a screencap but StackOverflow says I need a rep of at least 10)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

Follow the steps here:

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click OK.

If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that's exactly what I'm doing up through the point where you say "Click Next". That's when I get 'Your original request has been modified. "Android DDMS" so an update will be performed instead.'

But it doesn't do an update, nor does it give me any way to do one.