# No api levles option after update sdk in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i had a nice working eclipse but i had to use it for 3 weeks now and i decide to run a check-update in sdk manager (it finds some updates i install them )

today i try to open my eclipse and i am getting this message :

```
This Android SDK requires Android ToolKit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 22.3.0v201310242005-887826.  Please update ADT to the latest version
```

(in Android SDK manager  in tools i have Android SDK Tools 22.6.3 checked as installed)

i am checking for updates but i get one message : `no updates were found`
and one error : `some sites could not be found. see the error log for more detail`

```
and details are : Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at http:/content.xml.
Host name may not be null
Unable to read repository at http:/content.xml.
Host name may not be null
```

after that my project has lot of errors and when i try to choose Properties and then android to see the list of api levels... there is nothing there

Comment: check this link..hope it helps you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6

Comment: I was facing that problem a few days ago just because i would have to start eclipse (Run as administrator).
People were saying to uninstall that plugin and reinstall it but I did not find any proper solution to it. I downloaded the eclipse again and now i am free of that error.

Comment: ok i find the solution... i download the new sdk and install manual again... over the old directory

now it works

Comment: Thanks ranjit Pati.. now  i saw your post..  yes i did the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the ADT plugin.

If for some reason the update is not working from the online repo you can manually download and install the plugin.

You can find the download link and instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting).

For a self-contained answer here is the [current version](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip).

And the instructions to install the plugin:

1. Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it):
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.3.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
   If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
10. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.