# "Enter an application name" error in New Android Application window despite having entered it

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, adt, eclipse-adt, eclipse-luna

I installed ADT with Eclipse and SDK in /home/user-name/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321, /opt/eclipse and /opt/android-sdk-linux respectively.

Previously I didn't experience any problems when working with ADT. I tried to install Eclipse and wanted to add the plugin to it. Then I installed Eclipse and added the SDK to it. Now the newly installed Eclipse Luna is working fine but my ADT is not creating a new Android project.

It's is showing the error "Enter an application name (shown in launcher)" and the red x mark will be on Theme (see image below).
[image: ADT software Error]

Is it not possible to work on the two of them?

PS: I am using two different work spaces for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADT, make sure you have specified the SDK Location:

```
Window->preferences->android
```

If that preference is missing, then make sure ADT is installed in your new Eclipse Luna: see "[Install ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)"

> - Start Eclipse, then select `Help > Install New Software`.
> - Click Add, in the top-right corner.
> - In the `Add Repository` dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Even if it is already installed, it is still [important to click  `Help > Install New Software` and enter the https url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515716/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your response,but my error is in ADT software,not in eclipse-Luna.

Comment: @TortoiseWalker I agree, but this is valid even for ADT, not just your new Eclipse Luna. See my revised answer.