# Can't Update The Android Developer Toolkit (ADT) TO Version 23

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am Facing a problem when Opening the Eclipse IDE For developing Android Apps .

this Dialog Appears When Eclipse Starting

[image: This Dialog Appears When Eclipse Starting]

I see a lot of questions here but that didn't works with my Problem

---

i tried to do what this articles
[Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6)

when i follow the steps and did everything this error appear to me

[image]

Error Msg :

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Android Development Toolkit 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 23.0.3.1327240)
    Android Development Toolkit 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt [23.0.3.1327240]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.0.1.v201305230001--685705]
```

any one of you guys have a solution for that ??

Best Regards !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues had this issue as well. After spending half a day fixing it eventually,he removed his Eclipse and downloaded the newest version of ADT (Eclipsed based).

I suggest if you do not have many plugins installed on the current version, try doing the same. It just saves your time.

Comment: my eclipse only have a android plugins
from where i can download fully eclipse with new ADT ?
AND WHAT About the Workspaces it will still works with new adt right ?

Comment: Download it from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html Your workspace will be fine

Comment: @hommi Thanks Dear , It works fine With me :)
(Best Answer)

Comment: @hoomi can i copy the sdk from previous folder or i have to update it in latest ADT

Comment: so when your car i broken you just uninstall it and download new instead for fixing it?

Comment: Uninstalling Eclipse should be the last resource. Other not-so-heavy solution is uninstalling all the currently installed android plugins (About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> select the Android ones and 'Uninstall...' [Restart Eclipse]) and then installing the latest android plugin versions.