# Eclipse: Please update ADT to latest version, but none is available?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open up my `Eclipse` (for android) i'm getting the following message:

[image]

However, whenever I press "`check for updates"` it says that none are available.

I also **cannot** even create a `new android project`, it allows me to enter project name etc which are definitely correct, but I cannot click finish to create the project. I.e.:

[image]

What is the issue, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you ever heard about screenshot?

Comment: I have added in screenshots?

Comment: Taking pictures with your smartphone is not the same as screenshots.

Comment: this was a screenshot using printscreen on laptop

Comment: Update the tools using the "Install new software" feature. "Check for updates" won't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common issue, which costed me some hairs from my head. It was very difficult to fix, and the solution is not very "nice" but it's the only one that worked for me :

- Totally delete the old ADT and Eclipse directory
- Check that there is no other directory containing any other ADT / SDK / Eclipse installation (double-check it, I had two SDK directories)
- Reinstall Eclipse, Android SDK and ADT linked from Google sites (NOT the bundled version which does not work !)
- If on Windows, go to `Computer/Properties/Avanced System Properties/Environment Variables` and check that ANDROID_HOME points to the correct directory

Ok, this seems overkill, and may take almost an hour depending on you network speed, but let's face it : how many time did you already spend on this problem ?