# In eclipse, new "android application project" does not create

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, adt

I want to start programming for android so I downloaded Eclipse and installed ADT Plugin on it and downloaded the Android SDK Now when I want to create a new android project in "File->New->Android Application Project" it directs me to a page that wants "Application name" & "Project name" etc. so I filled the fields like this:

Application name: Hello

Project name: Hello

Package name: test.example.hello

Minimum required SDK: API8: Android 2.2(Froyo)

Target SDK: API16: Android 4.1(Jelly Bean)

Compile with:

theme: none

I installed all of "SDK Platforms" and "Google APIs" in Android SDK Manager
But the "Next" button is disabled! in the top of the page it says: " A package name cannot start or end with a dot" and there is a tiny red thing(cross) near the theme field so I cannot create a new project what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a target API to compile your code against.. See, you have left "compile with:" blank.. I usually choose to compile it with the target SDK.

If you do not find any API available for compiling against, you probably haven't installed any from the Android SDK Manager...

Comment: I said that I installed all of "SDK Platforms" and "Google APIs" in Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

Someone has asked and solved this before.

[eclipse, new android application project, "next button" is disabled in section that wants the project name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600068/eclipse-new-android-application-project-next-button-is-disabled-in-section-t).

Maybe you didn't installed the SDK platform.

Comment: I said that I installed all of "SDK Platforms" and "Google APIs" in Android SDK Manager

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that, have you try other methods mentioned in that question, like changing workspace ?

Comment: If you haven't solve the problem, how about using this ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html